# vmc login error

Tags: cloud-foundry

Having a problem when trying to login with my cloudfoundry credentials using vmc at the mac osx commandline.

I've tried:
vmc login
vmc -t login
vmc add-user MYEMAIL --email MYEMAIL --passwd MYPASSWORD
vmc login MYEMAIL --password MYPASSWORD

All of which result in a user authentication error. I have used the original password from my welcome email and have reset my password, trying each with the above commands.

My current email/password combo authenticates perfect when logging into the login.cloudfoundry.com website..

any ideas?

EDIT: For login using the MicroCloud, per Andy's answer fixed by running `vmc register`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your target? What do you get when you type: vmc target

Your target should be https://api.cloudfoundry.com

```
vmc target https://api.cloudfoundry.com
```

Comment: Yes thx, I already set my target to: http://api.lvxn0va.cloudfoundry.me which is accessible on the web.

Comment: I was able to login using the above as you suggested, thanks,  but I am using the cloudfoundry microcloud with that custom subdomain. Unfortunately their documentation for the microcloud doesn't point out the differences between the two.  I still cannot login to vmc when I set my target to http://api.lvxn0va.cloudfoundry.me/ - My credentials are the same

Comment: Did you use vmc register to create a user in your Micro Cloud Foundry instance?

Comment: Thx Andy that did it. Was looking all around in the docs for something like that.